# Attaching screenshots to JUnit test reports

Tags: javascript, jenkins, junit, protractor, screenshot

We run our tests on Jenkins using `Protractor` generating a JUnit XML test report via `JUnitXmlReporter` from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters).

Is it possible to attach screenshots, with the current state of an application under test at the time of a failure, to the JUnit XML report and then show these screenshots on the Jenkins test report page?

From what I understand, there is no single existing solution/tool to solve this problem, there are multiple things involved. Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I remember seeing it in a YouTube video I watched years ago. Kohsuke Kawaguchi's talk [Jenkins Selenium Meetup: Kohsuke Kawaguchi on how Jenkins + Selenium = Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzAnUzqAsqE) at around the 18 minute mark.

Comment: Nice, very relevant - what I learned from the talk: there is a jenkins plugin which looks for attachment paths in the test outputs. Now, all I need to do is to figure out the easiest way to take a screenshot on a Protractor/Jasmine test failure and write it down to the stdout. I'll post something once I make it work, thanks!